# Issue with IF Statement Java

Tags: java, if-statement

I have created a boolean called `multiplay`.

```
private boolean multiplay;
```

within my `public Game()` I have:

```
// make a player
player = new Player(this);
if(multiplay == true) {
   player2 = new Player(this);
}
```

Within the actually class file I have created a method:

```
public void startMutliPlayer() {
   multiplay = true;
}
```

What I am trying to do is when `startMultiPlayer` is called it will set the boolean `multiplay` as `true`, therefore, two players will be added to the frame not one. if 'startMultiPlayer' is not called it will only add one player.

At the moment it only adds one player not two when I called `startMultiPlayer`.

UPDATE:

Was able to sort this issue out using the following code:

```
// Make Players (Single & MultiPlayer)
        if (multiplay == false) {
            player = new Player(this);
            player.setPosition(startPosition);
            player.move(new Vec2(-210, 0));
            multiplay = true;
        } else if(multiplay == true) {
            player = new Player(this);
            player.setPosition(startPosition);
            player.move(new Vec2(-210, 0));player2 = new Player(this);
            player2.setPosition(startPosition);
            player2.move(new Vec2(-150, 0));
            multiplay = false;
        }

public static void startMutliPlayer() {
        multiplay = false;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Post an SSCCE. The code you posted is not sufficient to understand what the problem is. Also, `if (multiplay)` is sufficient. No need to compare a boolean with true to get a boolean.

Comment: @JBNizet What do i need to post. I am not getting any errors the other player does not load. Thats the issue i am having here. Btw, i set it as false and now the player appears but it appears even though i did not call it.

Comment: I think that you have to move the `if` statement within `startMultiplayer()` methode, therfore you will verify the stat of the `multiplay` variable, and add player.

Comment: You must post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Give the flow of your calling code. What object do you create first, what methods you call on the object? What object do you create next?

Comment: Your code still doesn't show where you are calling startMultiPlay?

Comment: @user93353 I call that from another class.

Comment: You should show that code also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which object of the Game class are you calling startMultiPlay on? Since it will always be called after the Game constructor is called, it will not work - because when the Game ctor is called, multiplay will be false.

On way to fix this is

```
private boolean multiplay;
```

needs to be changed to

```
private static boolean multiplay;
```

Also make startMultiPlayer as static and call it before you create a Game object.

Another way is not to create Player's in Game's ctor.
Have to methods startMultiPlayer and startSinglePlayer - create one or two Player objects in these methods respectively.

Comment: I think for OP you have to give some more theory..I feel so.(I am not downvoter)

Comment: @JamesDanny you should up vote the answer it if helped. **Please comment if you down votes**

Answer (score 0):

Create a method in your `Game` class, i.e.

```
public void setMultiplay(boolean multiplay) {
  this.multiplay = multiplay; // scope
  if (multiplay) {
    player2 = new Player(this);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, This worked however the key buttons do not work and i get this error. Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at game.KeyHandler.keyPressed(KeyHandler.java:76)

Comment: This is a separate problem, you should ask a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are calling the method startMultiPlayer() on an object of the class Game.
However, the constructor is the first thing to be executed when you create an object in Java.
    Game game = new Game();
    game.startMultiPlayer();
will execute the following lines in this order:

```
// make a player
player = new Player(this);
if(multiplay == true) {
   player2 = new Player(this);
}
multiplay = true;
```

which means multiplay is set to true after you check if it's true. Therefore, you will still be in singleplayer mode.

Try checking if multiplay is true after calling (or not calling) the `startMultiPlayer()` method.

*Also note that you can simply write `if(multiplay)` instead of `if(multiplay==true)` since if-statements in Java can only take booleans. But that's personal preference, this is probably optimized automatically anyway.*